# Autoresolve typescript dependencies

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, gruntjs, typescript

I am tired of handling reference order of TypeScript files on my own. Is there a tool to do this work for me? I tried visual studio and gruntjs approach which turns all `.ts` files into 1 `.js` file. But they both ignore file order so I for example get big js file like:

```
class A : B 
{

}();

class B
{

}();
```

And my angular application fails to run because B has not been initialised yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to ease the ordering of dependencies is to create a `_references.ts` file that acts as the sole source of this information:

```
///<reference path="b.ts" />
///<reference path="a.ts" />
```

You can then simply reference this one file from all of the others:

```
///<reference path="_references.ts" />

class A extends B {

}
```

Alternatively, if you switch to external modules and use a module loader, the import statements supply all of the information needed to ensure the ordering works.

Comment: I more like internal modules, but is it possible to make typescript compiler show me error that I didnt referenced the b.ts file while using class B in for example c.ts ?

Comment: It is a runtime error, so it isn't really something TypeScript can check (it would have to statically analyse all of your HTML files and check the ordering of your script tags).

Comment: What If I have all my typescript code compiled into 1 javascript file?It should be easy to determine the order in this case

Comment: It is theoretically possible, although it would cost in terms of compilation times. The key point being that the compiler doesn't currently do that - you the `_references.ts` file can be used to tell it the order.